# OneSignal: hide bell button on some pages(routes)

Tags: angular, typescript, onesignal

I have an SPA(angular v.5) application. I'm importing oneSignal by CDN. I have to hide the bell icon from one signal in some routes(pages). I tried something like this:

```
...
const oneSignal = window.OneSignal
try{
oneSignal.init({
/* My config */
}).then(() => {
  this.displayButton$.subscribe(value => {
    if (value) {
      oneSignal.notifyButton.launcher.show();
    } else {
      oneSignal.notifyButton.launcher.hide();
    }
  });
})
} catch(err) {
...
```

This solution works perfectly for all browser except Safari(v. 12 MacOS). It happens because on safari `oneSignal.notifyButton` is equal to null. I didn't find those `show` and `hide` methods in docs. I found them in oneSignal code. I thought it could be because some polyfill is missed but I stuck with this idea.

If anyone can help me with that or provide some other solution to hide this bell on some pages. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Better to subscribe to the current URL and toggle your bell icon on the basis of that. for example

Somewhere in your global service, you have code:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
  if (this.router.url.includes('someURL')) {
    this.isBellIconShown = false;
  } else {
    this.isBellIconShown = true;
  }
}
```

and then you can use `isBellIconShown` as toggle